# Filter dataframe using a second dataframe value by value

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I always have had trouble with loops so I am asking here. 
2 dataframes. 1 very large and 1 much smaller. Sample versions below.

```
Dataframe 1

ID        Value
1         apples
1         apples
1         bananas
1         grapes
1         mangoes
1         oranges
1         grapes
1         apples
1         grapes
2         apples
2         apples
2         passionfruits
2         bananas
2         apples
2         apples
2         passionfruits
2         grapes
2         mangoes
2         apples
3         apples
3         bananas
3         oranges
3         apples
3         grapes
3         grapes
3         passionfruits
3         passionfruits
3         oranges
4         apples
4         oranges
4         mangoes
4         bananas
4         grapes
4         grapes
4         grapes
4         apples
4         oranges
4         grapes
4         mangoes
4         mangoes
4         apples
4         oranges
5         passionfruits
5         apples
5         oranges
5         oranges
5         mangoes
5         grapes
5         apples
5         bananas

Dataframe 2

Value
apples
apples
bananas
grapes
mangoes
mangoes
grapes
apples
apples
```

The different IDs in dataframe 1 are considered as sets. The dataframe 2 in its entirety will be an approximate or exact match to one of the sets. I know there is plenty of code to filter using the entire dataframe 2 to match with 1. **But that is not what I require. I require it to filter sequentially value by value with conditions attached.** The condition should be whether the previous value matches.

So in this example with the first value nothing happens because all IDs have 'apples'. The second value = 'apples' given that previous value='apples' filters out ID = 4 because it doesnt contain 'apples' occurring twice in a row. Now in the filtered dataframe 1 we search for the third value and so on. It stops only when 1 ID set remains in Dataframe 1. So in this case after the 3rd iteration. Result should be

```
Dataframe 1

ID        Value
1         apples
1         apples
1         bananas
1         grapes
1         mangoes
1         oranges
1         grapes
1         apples
1         grapes
```

Comment: For ID 1, it is `mangoes` followed by `oranges`, but in data.frame it is `mangoes`, then `mangoes`

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach with `data.table` (an adaptation from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48661339/2204410)):

```
# load packages
library(data.table)

# create a function which calculates match-score with 'df2$Value'
maxscore <- function(x, y) {
  m <- mapply('==', shift(x, type = 'lead', n = 0:(length(y) - 1)), y)
  max(rowSums(m, na.rm = TRUE))
}

# calculate the match-score for each group
# and filter out the other groups
setDT(df1)[, score := maxscore(Value, df2$Value), by = ID
           ][score == max(score)][, score := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    ID   Value
> 1:  1  apples
> 2:  1  apples
> 3:  1 bananas
> 4:  1  grapes
> 5:  1 mangoes
> 6:  1 oranges
> 7:  1  grapes
> 8:  1  apples
> 9:  1  grapes
> ```

---

You can use that function in a `dplyr`-chain as well (but you will still need the `data.table`-package for the `shift`-function):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(m = maxscore(Value, df2$Value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(m == max(m)) %>% 
  select(-m)
```

An alternative implementation of the `maxscore`-function (inspired by @doscendo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660951/2204410)):

```
maxscore2 <- function(x, y) {
  w <- which(x == y[1])
  v <- sapply(w, function(i) sum(x[i:(i+(length(y)-1))] == y, na.rm = TRUE))
  max(v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can merge `Value` for each `ID` using a token separator (say `#`) and then write a custom function that compare how many sequential tokens were matched. Finally, select data for `ID` that has got the maximum match.

```
library(dplyr)

# This function matches and count tokens separated by `#`
# matched_count ("a#b#c","a#e#c#d")  will return 1
matched_count <- function(x, y){
  x_v <- strsplit(x, split = "#")[[1]]
  y_v <- strsplit(y, split = "#")[[1]]
  max_len <- max(length(x_v), length(y_v))
  length(x_v) <- max_len
  length(y_v) <- max_len
  sum(x_v==y_v,na.rm = TRUE)
}    


Dataframe1 %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(CompStr = paste0(Value, collapse="#")) %>% #collapse values for ID
  mutate(CompStrdf2 = paste0(Dataframe2$Value, collapse="#")) %>% 
  mutate(max_match = matched_count(CompStr, CompStrdf2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(max_match == max(max_match)) %>%
  select(ID, Value)

# ID Value  
# <int> <chr>  
# 1     1 apples 
# 2     1 apples 
# 3     1 bananas
# 4     1 grapes 
# 5     1 mangoes
# 6     1 oranges
# 7     1 grapes 
# 8     1 apples 
# 9     1 grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning the `Values` in each group into a string and comparing their string edit distance. `adist` - *Compute the approximate string distance between character vectors. The distance is a generalized Levenshtein (edit) distance, giving the minimal possibly weighted number of insertions, deletions and substitutions needed to transform one string into another.*

```
string_edit_dist <- function(vec1, vec2) {
    c(adist(paste0(vec1, collapse=""), paste0(vec2, collapse="")))
}    

ind <- which.min(sapply(seq_along(unique(df1$ID)), function(i) string_edit_dist(df1$Value[df1$ID==i], df2$Value)))
df1[df1$ID==ind, ]

  # ID   Value
# 1  1  apples
# 2  1  apples
# 3  1 bananas
# 4  1  grapes
# 5  1 mangoes
# 6  1 oranges
# 7  1  grapes
# 8  1  apples
# 9  1  grapes
```

Here is the `string_edit_distance` for each group

```
sapply(seq_along(unique(df1$ID)), function(i) string_edit_dist(df1$Value[df1$ID==i], df2$Value))
# 7 35 45 46 27
```