# R count number of instances of specific integer sequence

Tags: r, match, sequence

I am having trouble which what I thought would be a simple issue.

I have the following vector (which is actually a column in a dataset)

```
example_data <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 9, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5)
```

I want to find the number of times that `c(4, 5, 6)` occurs, exactly in that order. In the above example this would be 4 times.

I have attempted using `%in%` and `grepl()` but neither of those have proved successful. I have also tried collapsing the vector into one sequence and matching that way but no luck.

I just feel like I am missing something very obvious, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @akrun unfortunately that just gives me the number of times 4, 5 and 6 occur, regardless of order.

Comment: Yeah, i realized that, so I corrected in the solution

Comment: Related: [Get indexes of a vector of numbers in another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660606/get-indexes-of-a-vector-of-numbers-in-another-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Matching a sequence in a larger vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244006/matching-a-sequence-in-a-larger-vector), [Match a vector inside a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612584/match-a-vector-inside-a-vector), [R: find indexes of vector in another vector (if it exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53303614/r-find-indexes-of-vector-in-another-vector-if-it-exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to get the `lead` of the values with `shift` (from `data.table`) into a `list`, then `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` after comparing with the values of interest 4, 5, 6, and get the `sum` of TRUE elements

```
library(data.table)
sum(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, shift(example_data, 0:2, type = 'lead'), 4:6)))
#[1] 4
```

---

or `paste` the data into a string and with `str_count` from `stringr` get the count of the pattern '456'

```
library(stringr)
str_count(paste(example_data, collapse=""), '456')
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works well! Though I need to study that first method a bit to ensure I understand it! :p

I like the str_count method - more intuitive to me. And I think that was where I was trying to get.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In base R you could use: `regexpr("456",paste(example_data,collapse = ""))[1]`