# R: find indexes of vector in another vector (if it exists)

Tags: r

I would like to know the starting index of a vector in another vector. For example, for `c(1, 1)` and `c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)` it would be 4.

What is important I want to look for *exactly* the same vector. Thus, for `c(1, 1)` inside `c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)` it is FALSE as `c(1, 1) != c(1, 1, 1)`.

For now I am checking if the short vector is contained in the long like this:

```
any(with(rle(longVec), lengths[as.logical(values)]) == length(shortVec)
```

But I don't know how to determine the index of it...

Comment: c(1,1) also doesn't equal c(1,1,0). How do you decide that your example is false but mine should give you 1 as the result?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean but for c(1,1) inside c(1,1,0) using the function I prepared it is TRUE. Just I would need the index (1 in this case) as well

Comment: Related: [Get indexes of a vector of numbers in another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660606/get-indexes-of-a-vector-of-numbers-in-another-vector)

Comment: Based on the link provided by @Henrik, you can start with `shortVec <- c(1,1); longVec <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1); idx <- which(longVec == shortVec[1]); idx[sapply(idx, function(i) all(longVec[i:(i+(length(shortVec)-1))] == shortVec))][1]`

Comment: @jake-ferguson dude, why did you delete your other question? I put quite a bit of effort in answering it.

Answer (score 3):

This function should work:

```
my_function <- function(x, find) {
  # we create two matrix from rle function
  m = matrix(unlist(rle(x)), nrow=2, byrow = T) 
  n = matrix(unlist(rle(find)), nrow=2, byrow = T)

  # for each column in m we see if its equal to n
  temp_bool = apply(m, 2, function(x) x == n) # this gives a matrix of T/F
  # then we simply sum by columns, if we have at least a 2 it means that we found (1,1) at least once
  temp_bool = apply(temp_bool, 2, sum)

  # updated part
  if (any(temp_bool==2)) {
    return(position = which(temp_bool==2)+1)
  } else {
    return(position = FALSE)
  }

}


my_function(x, find)
#[1] 4

my_function(y, find)
#[1] FALSE
```

To make it more clear here I show the results from those two `apply`:

```
apply(m, 2, function(x) x == n)
#       [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  # TRUE-TRUE on column 3 is what we seek

apply(temp_bool, 2, sum)
#[1] 1 1 2 0 1
```

Example data:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1)
y <-  c(1,0,1,1,1,0)
find <- c(1,1) # as pointed this needs to be a pair of the same number
```

Comment: That's a very cool and elegant solution! Never heard about rle before -- could've been so useful to me in the past!

Comment: But this assumes that find is going to be a run of equal values, doesn't it? It won't work for find=c(1,0), for example, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct, nice catch. But maybe that's not a case op needs. I'll see if I can improve it.

Comment: But that's doing exaclty the same as my one-line solution in the question, right? We get T or F, but still we don't get the index of it... @RLave

Comment: what I would like to have is to get for example 4 (Index of first occurance) or false if we don't find the vector inside the longer one

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `shortVec` contains only ones and `longVec` contains only zeros and ones use `rle` and `rep` to create a vector `lens` the same length as `longVec` such that each element in each run is replaced by that run's length.  Then multiply that by `longVec` to zero out the elements corresponding to 0 in `longVec`.  Now return the indices corresponding to elements equal to `length(shortVec)` and take the first.

```
lookup <- function(shortVec, longVec) {
  lens <- with(rle(longVec), rep(lengths, lengths))
  which(lens * longVec == length(shortVec))[1]
}

lookup(c(1,1), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
## [1] 4

lookup(c(1,1), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1))
## [1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for the examples below.

```
a <- c(1,1)
b <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0)
c <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0)

f <- function(x, y) {
  len.x <- length(x)
  len.y <- length(y)
  for(i in 1:(len.y - (len.x - 1))) {
    if(identical(y[i:(i + (len.x - 1))], x)){
      if(y[i + len.x] != x[len.x] & y[i - 1] != x[1]) {return(TRUE)}
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
f(a, b)
# TRUE
f(a, c)
# FALSE
```

Comment: It fails if x exists as the first or last elements of y though