# Find the position of a string sequence in other vector

Tags: r, string

Given the following two character vectors

```
stringA = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "BB", "DD", "CC")
stringB = c("BB", "CC")
```

I want to find the positions of `stringB` within `stringA`.

The result should be a vector of length `stringB`, hence for this example: `c(2, 3)`. 
A vector of length one only containing the start position of the sequence (here: 2) would also be ok (since I know the length of `stringB` and could operate further with it).

It can be assumed that the sequence of `stringB` is unique within `stringA`.

Comment: How about `pmatch(stringB, stringA)` ?

Comment: might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660606/get-indexes-of-a-vector-of-numbers-in-another-vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are looking for the position where the *whole* sequence of `stringB` starts in `stringA` you can use:

```
which(rowSums(!sapply(seq(stringB), function(i) stringB[i] ==
   stringA[i:(length(stringA)-length(stringB)+i)])) == 0)
#[1] 2
```

Comment: I ended up using this answer since it is the only one that worked for my practical problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're after positions of elements in vectors. Positions are equivalent to indices.

To grab TRUE indices (that is, those indices the elements of which evaluate to TRUE on some condition--in your case, that the unique elements of `stringA` be contained in `stringB`), you can use `which`:

```
which(unique(stringA) %in% stringB)
[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking every position of stringB in stringA, then you could use this:
`lapply(stringB, function(x) which(x == stringA))`

alternatively, if you just want a vector containing the first position of stringB in stringA, you could try this:
`sapply(stringB, function(x) which(x == stringA)[1])`

Comment: or use this: `lapply(stringB, function(x) which(x == unique(stringA)))`